# Which query performs better when searching a row where a column has maximum?

Tags: optimization, select, subquery, limits

Consider a simple table for example purposes:

```
person(name varchar, age int)
```

I have a task to retrieve the oldest person. Which query is better in general for such problems?

Query 1: criteria with subquery for maximum value

```
SELECT p.* FROM person p WHERE p.age = (SELECT MAX(age) FROM person);
```

Query 2: ordering and selecting first row

```
SELECT p.* FROM person ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I'm currently using PostgreSQL, but the question is I think platform independent.

Comment: Look at the execution plan (using `explain analyze`) and you will know. Btw: your two statements are not equivalent. The first one will return multiple rows if multiple person are the same age, the second one will not.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you, you're right of course, I forgot to note that "if we assume that only one person is the oldest"

Comment: In both cases the speed should be similar and mainly depend on indexing.

Comment: I will do some explain analyze when I have time to setup a test table. My guess - which I didn't want to include in the question - would be that first one should be faster on large tables because sorting seems to be more expensive than seq scan with aggregation.

Comment: @dnoeth I didn't mention indexing because that can change things quite much indeed, so for the matter of theoretical discussion I assumed that no indexing or other lower-level optimizations are applied.

Comment: Actually, the first query could return more than one row if there are multiple people with the same age that is the oldest.  The second query will only return one row and if there are multiple individuals with the same age, which one are you going to get?

Comment: @QueueMann please see the second comment

Comment: I wouldn't call indexing a low-level optimization. And if there is no index on `age`, both queries would have horrible performance with a big table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is as platform independent as you think but I've been doing some fairly extensive testing on this in SQL Server recently and the first query was interestingly the fastest.  This was comparing against a number of "tricks" in SQL Server including using CROSS APPLY and windowing functions. But again YMMV in PostgreSQL.

Unless I'm mistaken (I don't know PostgreSQL) your second query will actually come up faster but only because it's going to give you the age for one person.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is query2 (not exactly the same as query 1 though), but you will have to check the plan to be sure. Btw:

```
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

is the standard equivalent to LIMIT, it is supported by DB2 LUW (>= 7), Oracle (>= 12c), PostgreSQL (>= 8.4) and SQL server (>= 2012). Yet another option is to use an analytical function like rank:

```
SELECT age, name
FROM (
    SELECT age, name, rank() over (order by age desc) as rnk
    FROM person
) 
WHERE rnk = 1;
```